# Unable to install Python 3 on OSX 10.2

Tags: python, macos

I had some issues with installing Python 3 on my Mac with OSX 10.12. Now I have stuck on point when Python is installed but is not properly linked.

I installed it via homebrew by `brew install python@3.9` and command python3 gives me

```
pavelprdel@Pavels-Mac-mini ~ % python3
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep  3 2021, 04:31:11) 
[Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

But with command python I get

```
pavelprdel@Pavels-Mac-mini ~ % python
zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin/python3.9.7
pavelspurny@Pavels-Mac-mini ~ %
```

I have found solution via brew link --overwrite python
command but I only get this

```
Warning: Already linked: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7
To relink, run:
  brew unlink python@3.9 && brew link python@3.9
```

And `relink` doesn't work, I used `which python` command and it seems that it is installed in different location

```
python: aliased to /usr/local/bin/python3.9.7
```

I have also installed python from https://www.python.org/ but result is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just link it manually:

```
# remove current link
unlink /usr/local/bin/python

# add new link
ln -s $(which python3) /usr/local/bin/python
```

Also check `$PATH` variable:

```
echo ${PATH}

...:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:...
```

`/usr/local/bin` must prepend `/usr/bin` because here is default python 2.x interpreter `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/local/bin/python` must be called first

Also I [don't recommend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3) to override system's `/usr/bin/python` with `python3`, it should be reverted if already overridden

Check for upvoted 41 times warning (However that is not a so big problem for mac OS in compare to Linux OS):

> Just a warning: Do not attempt to change the /usr/bin/python symlink to point to python3 instead of 2.7. Many programs available in the Ubuntu repos require /usr/bin/python to be compatible to python 2.x.

Anyway usually the `python` is used to run python 2.x and the `python3` to run python 3.x. I recommend to use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) (for shell session scope) or [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) (for project scope) to be able override python with python3 only where it needed.

In other cases execute python 3 via `python3` command is a normal practice

Answer (score 0):

A better way to install python is by downloading it from the following link:
`https://www.python.org/`. Then, click on the download tab and select the newest version.
This should fix your problem. Installing via brew might be outdated and does not always work on OSX.

Comment: I did it, but result is still the same.

Comment: @prdel99 Did you try uninstalling python first? You might have a broken version installed which causes this to happen. Try to uninstall python 3 and re-install it using the link.